# iPhone - Detect (recognize) a visual pattern or object using the device's camera

Tags: iphone, camera, pattern-recognition

I would like to develop a simple application to detect (recognize) a certain pattern (lets say the logo of a car manufacturer) using the iPhone's camera.

I don't know from were to start. Can you give me a hint? What framework are available for this type of image processing, are somewhere on the internet some tutorials related to this?

I just know about openCV, but I couldn't find a ported iPhone version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a port of openCV for the iPhone in [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it as soon as possible and I will let you know if it worked for me. Do you know anything about some related  tutorials? I am a newbie to this kind of image processing :D.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find anything.

Comment: Hmm...If you google "openCV openframeworks iphone" there are some people out there who seem to be trying to compile it (but most of the results are people having problems). Maybe if you ask them directly...